# Break xml in to multiple xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file. I am looлing for help to create multiple xml files from this xml file where ever it find different EmplId.

I tried to retrieve the distinct EmplId But not sure how to break the xml and loop through the entire xml file further.

Xml looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Connected>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>2</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Phone>##34</A.Phone>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
  </Emp>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
  </Emp>
</Connected>
```

Output will be 3 different Xml for 3 different EmplId

First Xml EmplID =1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Connected>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>
    <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
  </Emp>
</Connected>
```

Second Xml EmplId = 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Connected>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>2</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Phone>##34</A.Phone>
  </Emp>
</Connected>
```

Third Xml - EmplId  = 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Connected>
  <Emp>
    <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
    <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
  </Emp>
</Connected>
```

I have used below code to count distinct emplid

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:/Sample - code test.xml");
XmlNodeList count = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(@"//Connected/Emp/A.EMPLID");

int i = count.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(a => a.InnerText).Distinct().Count();
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Split an XML file into multiple XML Files based on nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455639/how-to-split-an-xml-file-into-multiple-xml-files-based-on-nodes)

Comment: Thanks for reply . But I am  not trying to break xml at each node. I have merged nodes if empl id is same. e.g EmplId =1 I have merged to create a one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq2xml much more convenient.

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var grouped = xml.Elements("Emp")
    .GroupBy(emp => emp.Element("A.EMPLID").Value);

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    var x = new XElement("Connected",
        new XElement("Emp",
            new XElement("A.EMPLID", group.Key),
            group.Select(g => g.Elements().Where(e => e.Name != "A.EMPLID"))));

    x.Save("file" + group.Key + ".xml");
}
```