# Create XMLs from xmls using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a XML file. I am looking for help to create multiple xml files from this xml file . The new xml will have the all the node with the same EmpID.I am using C# code and able to create xmls Xml looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Connected>
      <Emp>
          <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
          <A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>
      </Emp>
      <Emp>
          <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
          <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
      </Emp>
      <Emp>
          <A.EMPLID>2</A.EMPLID>
         <A.Phone>##34</A.Phone>
      </Emp>
      <Emp>
         <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
      </Emp>
      <Emp>
         <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
         <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
     </Emp>
    </Connected>
```

Output will be 3 different Xml for 3 different EmplId

1.xml

```
 <Connected>
     <Emp>
      <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
      <A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>
     </Emp>
    <Emp>
      <A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>
      <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
    </Emp>
</Connected>
```

2.xml

```
  <Connected>
      <Emp>
      <A.EMPLID>2</A.EMPLID>
      <A.Phone>##34</A.Phone>
      </Emp>
  </Connected>
```

3.Xml

```
 <Connected>
     <Emp>
         <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
     </Emp>
     <Emp>
         <A.EMPLID>3</A.EMPLID>
         <A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>
     </Emp>
 </Connected>
```

I am trying to do that C# code. Using XElement

```
      XElement x = new XElement("Connected",new XElement("Emp",new XElement("A.EMPLID", group.Key),group.Select(g => g.Elements().Where(e =>e.Name != "A.EMPLID"))));
```

But It is creating some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Connected>
<Emp>


<A.EMPLID>1</A.EMPLID>


<A.Phone>12##</A.Phone>


<A.Add>XXXXXXX</A.Add>


</Emp>


</Connected>
```

I need 3 xmls that will be generated for Empld but nodes should be exactly in same order.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and share the full code you have currently that produces the incorrect XML -- i.e. a [mcve]?  How does this relate to your previous questions [How to get value from XElement using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50258723/3744182) and [Break xml in to multiple xml using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50234718/3744182)?  Is this the same problem, or a different problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Connected></Connected>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var groups = doc.Descendants("Emp").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("A.EMPLID")).ToList();
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(ident);
                XElement root = doc1.Root;

                root.Add(group);

                doc1.Save(@"c:\temp\test" + group.Key + ".xml");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve that is by using XPath.

```
var empElements = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Emp[A.EMPLID=1]");
```

Above query will return all < Emp > nodes that belong to a particular ID (in this case 1).